# How to do this button in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, interface-design

I need to recreate this specific type of button using Inkscape:

[image]

Don't mind the text or the icon, just the button itself.
I've tried creating a rectangle with a solid color fill, then duplicating it and using an elliptic gradient in greyscale, finally I overlap both, but it does not look the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a slight lighter to darker red vertical gradient on the button shape by sampling the colours from the example graphic, then overlay with some blurred black rectangles with reduced opacity at the edges.

Group everything, then copy and paste the button shape in place, then apply it as a clipping path on the whole group.

For example

[image]

And here's the final result over a grey background (bottom), compared to the original graphic (top)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Billy! you nailed it! It was just what I needed! Thanks for the clear explanation!
It seems that my upvote won't show because my account is new and do not have enough reputation, but I accepted the answer!